# Nested Conditions In VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to excel and VBA so apologies for silly question or mistake.

i have some 2000 excel data in sheet2 and the data req in sheet 1

[image: Sample image please check this]

I need to know how many ticket which starts with INC and priority P2 P3 are there and same way how many tickets which starts with SR are there. also out of them how many are in closed state and how many are active.

```
Sub US_Data()
Dim z As Long
Dim C As Range

z = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For Each C In Sheet2.Range(Sheet2.Cells(2, 1), Sheet2.Cells(z, 1))
  If Left(C.Value, 3) = "INC" Then
    Sheet1.Cells(8, 6) = Sheet1.Cells(8, 6) + 1

  End If
Next C
End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Apologies i am stuck as i match Cells with "INC" using range now i am unable to check their priority and i also tried for loop but Left function was giving error

Comment: Is there any reason why you can’t use a pivot table to get your result? You may need additional columns to create attributes you can filter in, like a column with SR or INC (although you can filter a pivot table) but would that not work?

Comment: We get this data as automated report from a tool and is need to published. in a specific format only (Boss order's). so i cant use pivot table, is there any way i can use Left function with full address of cells like                                              z = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row           for i = 2 to z and than use left function as Left(Sheet2.Cells(z,1)).value,2 ="inc" then :

Comment: What has to be in a specific format? The outputted report of the summarized data you’re wanting to get? Sorry, I have to ask.

Comment: At the end of the day, I’m sure you can get the result you need with VBA but what if the boss wants to report on a new intersection of data? It won’t be flexible enough. If you can use a pivot table and the copy and paste the key figures into another sheet/workbook manually, I’d do that.

Comment: Inflow Backlog Total Inflow Closed Backlog Closed Total Closed Carry Forward 0 - 8 8 -. 24 1 - 3 days 3- 7 Days 7 - 10 Days > 10 Days 
P1 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
P2 662 0 662 656 0 656 6 0 0 6 0 0 0 6
P3 82 0 82 70 0 70 12 0 1 11 0 0 0 12
P4 101 0 101 89 0 79 22 0 0 22 0 0 0 22
 845 0 847 815 0 805 40 0 1 39 0 0 0 40

Comment: Something like that sorry for not properly formatted

Comment: don't use comments if you add clarification. Edit your question to do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub US_Data()
Dim z As Long
Dim HighCount as Long
Dim ModerCount as Long
Dim LowCount as Long
Dim OpenCount as Long
Dim ClosedCount as Long
Dim C As Range

z = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For Each C In Sheet2.Range(Sheet2.Cells(2, 1), Sheet2.Cells(z, 1))
    If Left(C.Value, 3) = "INC" Then
        If C.Offset(0,1).Value = "2 - High" Then HighCount = HighCount + 1
        If C.Offset(0,1).Value = "3 - Moderate" Then ModerCount = ModerCount + 1
        If C.Offset(0,1).Value = "4 - Low" Then LowCount = LowCount + 1
        If C.Offset(0,2).Value = "Closed" Then ClosedCount = ClosedCount + 1
        If C.Offset(0,2).Value = "Open" Then OpenCount = OpenCount + 1
    End If
Next C

MsgBox "I have counted " & HighCount & " times High, " & ModerCount & " times Moderate, " & LowCount & " times Low, and respectively " & OpenCount & " and " & ClosedCount & " open and closed instances.", vbOkOnly, "FYI"

Sheet1.Cells(8, 6) = HighCount
End Sub
```

This would be one way of doing it, you can fill the cells necessary with those variables.

Answer (score 1):

Why use VBA at all? This can be done with simple formulas. If you don't want to use pivot tables, manually create the headings (Blue in the screenshot), then put this formula into cell H3, copy across and down.

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$G3&"*",$B:$B,H$1,$C:$C,H$2)
```

[image]

Change the layout if you want. The point is that you don't need VBA for that. Formulas will be a lot faster than re-inventing a CountIfs with VBA.